# how to hide the tooltip of the sorting icon in the table header in Material React Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-react-table

I'm using "material-react-table" in a React JS project.

As per my requirements, I want to hide (remove) the tooltip that arises when hovering over the sorting icon in the table header in the Material React Table.

I tried a lot.

Can anyone help me sort out this?

Thanks in advance.

node version: v16.15.0
React version: v18.2.0
material-react-table: ^1.14.0

[Default one:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU0B3.png)

Want to remove the tooltip.